# Converting 4 bytes to an integer

Tags: python, binary

I am learning Python and would like to convert some data from a binary header file to integer values. I know the structure of the header file (already read in with C++) and I know which bytes form an integer. I have read through some of the answers and all of them point to the class `struct` and the method `unpack`. However I don't know how to feed in the 4 bytes and get an integer out. The bytes are now in a list. `mybytes = (byte[0],byte[1],byte[2],byte[3])`
Is it possible to pass this list to unpack and get the integer?

None of the answers so far worked for me. I tried the following:

```
val = struct.unpack("i", bytes(mybytes))
```

which then throws an error of the `mybytes` being not a string of 4 characters which is fair enough because it isn't string. But then how to feed binary data as string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you have your error.  What you tried works if there are four values.

```
>>> mybytes = 1,2,3,4
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('i',bytes(mybytes))
(67305985,)
>>> hex(_[0])
'0x4030201'
```

Comment: My apologies the above code works as is I had a terrible exchange of files! I get the right result  now!